# How to sort 10Gb file in java without using external API

Tags: java

I tried to search this question but i am not getting satisfactory answer.

Can any1 please help.

How to sort 10Gb file in java without using external API

Thanks.

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: You get no satisfactory answer because this is not a satisfactory question. What do you mean by sorting the file? Based on it's content? What content? What sorting? Please show some effort.

Comment: Yes sorting a file based on its contents. For instance if the file contains only names and i want to sort it without any built in java API. I am not aware of it. I was asked this question in interview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since a java byte array can only hold around 2GB of data, one option is to split this file into multiple byte arrays or an array of byte arrays, then sort the multiple arrays. You could also use a LinkedList and store your data as elements that way.

Comment: But how will i sort the contents in file after splitting it. I cannot use any API for example collections.sort or TreeMap.

Comment: @sussie You will have no choice but to implement a sorting algorithm by hand then. But I'm pretty sure this question was not asked to get a specific answer to it, but rather to see if you can think outside of the box and come up with a creative workaround for unnecessary limitations. Say: load the 10GB of data into a database and have it sort the data.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is [external sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting).